# Sort values of output of ls -alh without using -S option

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting

I have a script that recursively goes through directories and appends the result of running `ls -alh --block-size=KB | grep ^\-` to a file. I then need to sort the resulting file by decreasing file size in the same way that using the `-S` option would if it was used at the point where `ls` was called.

Comment: Use `stat` instead of `ls` Really -- `ls` is not well suited for scripting.

Comment: @dawg I have been told to use `ls`, and frankly I can't see what the problem with doing that is. Please remove your downvote, it's not very constructive for actually getting this answered.

Comment: Have you realized that the size field is the 5th, not the 4th?

Comment: @Jdamian I thought it was zero-indexed -_- I'll check to see if that works when I next have access to a Linux machine.

Comment: @RobMurray, re *"frankly I can't see..."*: see [Hastur's answer to a similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248062/165517).

Comment: @RobMurray, you have removed the commands you used from your question text. As one of those command was wrong, your code failed. But you have corrected by means of my comment above and now you show us like a solution. It's really tricky, isn't it?

Comment: @Jdamian Just trying to make it as useful to others as possible! Not denying I got it wrong originally :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The many issues of trying to parse `ls` are covered well in [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [Fixing Unix/Linux/POSIX Filenames](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html) for an idea of what others have tried before you.

Some additional reasons that your approach will not work reliably:

1. If you recurse over a device boundary, some versions of `ls` may add a column to show the new device ID and throw off your sorting and parsing;
2. You are using `sed` to remove the kB / mB / gB magnitude of the output of `ls -h`. That will sort a 2 byte file, 2 kilobyte file and 2 megabyte file all together as the same size.
3. The output of `ls` changes when you pipe it or display at the terminal also changing the logic of the parsing / sorting.

The solution is to use a glob and sort based on an added column to the output of `ls`.

We can use `dd` to create a list of test files of some known sizes:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=A  bs=2  count=1
dd if=/dev/zero of=B  bs=1024  count=2
dd if=/dev/zero of=C  bs=1024  count=3
dd if=/dev/zero of=D  bs=1024  count=150
dd if=/dev/zero of=E  bs=1024  count=2000
```

Resulting in:

```
$ ls -lh *
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel     2B Jan  8 20:52 A
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel   2.0K Jan  8 20:52 B
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel   3.0K Jan  8 20:52 C
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel   150K Jan  8 20:52 D
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel   2.0M Jan  8 20:52 E
```

If you sort the output of `ls` by the `-S` switch:

```
$ ls -lhS *
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel   2.0M Jan  8 20:52 E
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel   150K Jan  8 20:52 D
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel   3.0K Jan  8 20:52 C
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel   2.0K Jan  8 20:52 B
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel     2B Jan  8 20:52 A
```

You approach would remove the `M` `K` or `B` in column five and then sort on that. That would result in A, B and E sorting together.

---

(It is *possible* to *crudely* sort the output of `ls` like so:

```
$ ls -al | grep ^\- | sort -nrk 5
-rw-r--r--   1 andrew  wheel  2048000 Jan  8 20:52 E
-rw-r--r--   1 andrew  wheel   153600 Jan  8 20:52 D
-rw-r--r--   1 andrew  wheel     3072 Jan  8 20:52 C
-rw-r--r--   1 andrew  wheel     2048 Jan  8 20:52 B
-rw-r--r--   1 andrew  wheel        2 Jan  8 20:52 A
```

but that does not produce the output of `-h` that you have...)

---

The *correct* way is to do this is to use a [Decorate / Sort / Undecorate pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) with a glob.

```
for fn in *; do
    [ -f "$fn" ] || continue
    c1=$(($(wc -c < "$fn")))
    c2=$(ls -alh "$fn")
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$c1" "$c2"
done | sort -nrk 1 | cut -f 2
```

Result:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel   2.0M Jan  8 20:52 E
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel   150K Jan  8 20:52 D
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel   3.0K Jan  8 20:52 C
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel   2.0K Jan  8 20:52 B
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel     2B Jan  8 20:52 A
```

Which is the same as using `ls -lhS`

If you are recursing a file tree and writing to a file, the general methodology is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution which is good enough for my purposes, though the accepted answer is much better:

```
sed 's/kB//' files.tmp > files1.tmp #remove first instance of "kB" from each line
sed 's/ \+/ /g' files1.tmp > files2.tmp #replace all multiple spaces with single space
sort -k 5n,5 files2.tmp | tac > files3.tmp #sort by numeric file size and reverse
```

This only works due to giving the `--block-size=KB` option to `ls`.